# Masking two-values numpy array into 0-1 binary array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy array:

```
array(['NONRBP', 'RBP', 'NONRBP', 'RBP'], dtype=object)
```

What I want to do is to mask the above array giving value 1 to RBP and  0 to NONRBP, resulting in this:

```
array([0, 1, 0, 1])
```

What's the way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use a list comprehension here.

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> a=array(['NONRBP', 'RBP', 'NONRBP', 'RBP'], dtype=object)
>>> mask=array([int(x=='RBP') for x in a])
>>> mask
array([0, 1, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 4):

For a more numpy-like solution, you can do:

```
a = array(['NONRBP', 'RBP', 'NONRBP', 'RBP'], dtype=object)
mask = (a == 'RBP').astype(int)
```

You can also do the operation in place with:

```
a[:] = (a == 'RBP').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily numpy specific. You can use a list comprehension for the input to `array`'s constructor:

```
array(  [(1 if x == 'RBP' else 0) for x in l]  )
```